# definition of mixing component

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, mixing

definition of ergodic component: consider stationary dynamical system $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu, T)$, each ergodic component is $m(\cdot)=\mathbb{E}_{\mu}^{\mathcal{I}}\mathbf{1}_{(\cdot)}$, $\mathcal{I} $ is invariant $\sigma$-algebra. To explain it, $X$ can be divided into disjoin sets, supp of $m$ is one of this set, $T$ is closed on this set, $m$ is ergodic on this set.  so it looks like sub ergodic system on a smaller set.

however, I could not find the definition of mixing component. is the definition similar? can you refer some materials about it? Thanks!

Comment: By the ergodic decomposition theorem, every measure-preserving transformation can be decomposed into ergodic components. The corresponding statement for mixing is not true.

Comment: Thanks! yes, this is also what I constructed above. However, could not find what is mixing component. this concept arises in Young Lai-Sang paper: mixing rate and recurrent time. In the last page of her paper, she discussed the non-markov circle map, built up a tower for such map, decomposes tower as several mixing component. the concept is a little bit confusing.

Comment: Ok. So I assume she means ergodic components that happen to be mixing.